# Too broad space between tqdm progress bar

Tags: python, tqdm

When using tqdm in jupyter notebook, spaces between each progress bar in result are so broad.
How to decrease the space?

```
for i in tqdm(range(10)): pass
for i in tqdm(range(10)): pass
for i in tqdm(range(10)): pass
for i in tqdm(range(10)): pass
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxkYX.png)

Comment: I cannot reproduce any pronounced spaces in jupyter with tqdm on my machine (see screenshot here https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXlSL.png). Could you provide a screenshot to better illustrate the issue on your machine?

Comment: added the screenshot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot reproduce this in my environment, it looks like tqdm is trying to use a height of 20 rows to display the status bars.
The parameter connected to this is "nrows" (see [documentation of its **init** method](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/#__init__))
Here, the default fallback value is 20 rows (which would fit to your experience). Try adapting it accordingly, e.g.:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(10), nrows=4): pass
for i in tqdm(range(10), nrows=4): pass
for i in tqdm(range(10), nrows=4): pass
for i in tqdm(range(10), nrows=4): pass
```